# How to upgrade Windows 10 to latest build

Tags: windows-10

I use Windows 10 Home edition and my current version is `21H2` with build `19044.1566`. However, I see from [this website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes) that newer builds of Windows 10 are available. How can I update to the latest build `21364`? I do not see any updates in Windows Update Program nor find any documentation.

Comment: On your liked web page there are links to the Windows block which identify all the newer builds as "Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 21364" - thus they belong to beta versions of Windows that are not for productive use. If you still want to upgrade to them make sure you have a recent backup and then join the insider club https://insider.windows.com/en-us/getting-started

Comment: 1566 is the latest production build.   Be wary that the Insider Program may update you to Windows 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I update to the latest build 21364?

You are already on the current Windows 10 build.  Windows 10 Build 21364 was a Windows 10 Insider Preview build released in April 2021.  It has since expired and cannot be legitimately installed.

**If you want the features contained within that particular build, you would have to upgrade to Windows 11 21H2.**

**If you still want to try, despite a clear warning that you will be notified the build has expired and will be immediately and forcefully upgraded to the current Developer Windows 11 Insider Build.**  You certainly can try and upgrade your installation [here](https://uupdump.net/selectlang.php?id=62c51e33-08ad-4f39-b3a3-d2f5719547bd).

There are no current Windows 10 unexpired builds higher than 21364, which means installing a newer build is impossible.  **If you go the route of installing that expired build, you should know that it's impossible to downgrade your build to a lower number without a clean install.**

**Windows 10 19044.1566 is the current Windows 10 build.  Any major build higher than 19044 is considered to be Windows 11.**  That particular Windows 10 Insider Preview Windows 10 build was the last Insider Preview build before Windows 11 was actually announced.  22000.526 is the current Windows 11 21H2 build, while 22563+ will likely become Windows 11 22H2 at some point.

> I do not see any updates in Windows Update Program nor find any documentation.

Windows 10 Build 21364 was the last Windows 10 Insider Preview Developer channel build released.  Unless Microsoft changes what they have already announced, any future Windows 10 Insider Preview builds will happen within the Windows 10 Insider Preview Beta channel.

**Microsoft does not expect to release another feature update for Windows 10 at this time beyond 22H2.**  While a new feature update is not likely, there is always the possibility, that future improvements might be backported to Windows 10.

However, I do not expect any significant Windows 11 feature to be backported to Windows 10.  Whenever Microsoft talks about a new feature, the feature is exclusively coming to Windows 11.